# iOS app rejection - no crash log provided

Tags: ios, crash, submission

My iOS app got bounced because:

> We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have
>   attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Couple of questions:
1. I don't see a crash log attached in Appstoreconnect
2. Any idea how to process the crash log that Apple provides?

Comment: Did you get how to solve such issues?
I am currently banging my head for the same.

Comment: Regarding the crash-on-launch issue: - make it available to TestFlight in your itunesconnect account. Download it to a device and confirm you can see what Apple testers see. in My case, I needed to add the WebKit library to my app build - the app worked fine in debug, but it turns out needed to have that library specifically added - check to see if there's a library you need to add to your build in build phases

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I could see that app crashes when downloaded from TestFlight. Could you please guide me further on this issue. How to check which library is causing the problem and how to resolve that?

Comment: Did you found the solution?

Comment: Yes, please see comment above yours - you won't get a handle on how your app is behaving until you send it through TestFlight, which I wasn't doing - you'll then see it's behavior and now look at crashlogs for the app ON THE DEVICE (you can view them through Xcode organizer) - it should be pretty obvious from the logs what library is missing